# Redmine Install, only seeing file and folders. Possible Apache config issue

Tags: apache, redmine

So I tried to install redmine following the official instructions here:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall

And managed to successfully run with webrick (Step 9). After that (the machine is using Debian) I used this guide:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_210_on_Debian_Squeeze_with_Apache_Passenger

To "serve up" redmine. However after doing all of that I only see a list of files and folders. Here is the 000-default.conf that has the redmine configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        RailsEnv production
        RailsBaseURI /redmine

        <Directory /redmine>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Order deny,allow
                PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
                AllowOverride all
                Allow from all
                        RailsBaseURI /redmine
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

This is just the latest config I tried since I have added every option that I could come up with to try to get it to work. I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: Add `DirectoryIndex index.htm` (or your file extension) to `<Directory /redmine>`.

Comment: There is no file named index with any extension.

Answer (score 0):

Change your directory path:

```
<Directory "/redmine/public/">
```

See further information on Redmine at http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_configure_Apache_to_run_Redmine

Comment: Tried it. Did not work. Also I cannot follow the instructions in the link you gave me as it fails in the very first step. There is no dispatch.cgi.example. Only dispatch.fcgi.example. I assume that also requires fcgi which the very top of the page assures it is NOT needed.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, after much searching this worked - add to your Apache configuration the line:

```
PassengerAppRoot /opt/redmine
```

(change the path to where you unziped the redmine files)

See here for explanations:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerapproot

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12449924)

Comment: @Noel No. Please *read* answers when you are reviewing. This is not link-only - it contains information directly in the answer.